# How to refresh web page via thread that did not make the webpage using c# and tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, task

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestMethodRefresh());
}



private void TestMethodRefresh() {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
}
```

This is my current attempt at refreshing a web page via a task. This gives me an error 'Response is not available in this context.' I am wondering how such a thing is done in .net. In winforms it is trivial because you can invoke back onto the main thread to run your code async, I am not sure how to do that here.

```
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task myTask = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => TestMethodRefresh());
        System.Web.UI.PageAsyncTask asynctask = new PageAsyncTask(() => myTask);
    }

    private void TestMethodRefresh() {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(asynctask);
        Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
    }
```

This is my second attempt using asynctask as described in the comment below but the code never steps into TestMethodrefresh()

Comment: Take a look at this, it will help you understand how to use asynchronous methods on asp .net: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Gusman I updated my code to reflect using that api, however now my code does not run at all.

Comment: Well, you didn't read at all the document, there's no RegisterAsyncTask in your code, and without it and calling Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks() it will never execute...

Comment: @Gusman I read it more closely. However, after adding the code above and setting my web form attribute 'async = "true" ' my page does not load anymore. I feel like there should be a better way to do this simple thing.

Comment: No, there isn't, async tasks must be registered in order to ASP .net know about them so it doesn't returns the page content until the async task has finished. It spits any error or it just gets hung? also, instead of StartNew try Task.Run, StartNew may try to run it on main thread and it can lead to a deadlock I presume ,while Task.Run will create a new thread.

Comment: @Gusman I am not using startnew in my second attempt. I am making a task and sending that as a function of task to the PageAsyncTask constructor. I am not sure why it would cause my page to never load upon starting debugging. It does not spit an error on the code behind or chrome console.